# Concatenate strings using preprocessor in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, string-concatenation

How to concatenate two strings (one of them is stored in a variable) in **C** using preprocessors?

For example how to do this?

```
#define CONCAT(x,y) x y

//ecmd->argv[0] is equal to "sometext"
myfunc(CONCAT("/", ecmd->argv[0]), ecmd->argv[0]); //error: expected ')' before 'ecmd'
```

Comment: I think using macros is not the right way to do this.  You'll end up inlining buffer allocation and string functions - you might as well use a function instead, which will be typesafe and debuggable.

Comment: I am already doing it with function, I am just curious to do this using preprocessors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't concatenate them using a macro like that.  using the preprocessor, only raw strings (either string literals or names) can be concatenated.

You have to use `strcat` or some other technique to combine the strings.  For example:

```
char * buf = malloc(strlen(ecmd->argv[0]) + 2);
buf[0] = '/'; buf[1] = '\0';
strcat(buf, ecmd->argv[0]);
```

Comment: To elaborate: The pointer `ecmd` doesn't even exist when the preprocessor is running, nor does the memory it will later reference, so there cannot be any data that the preprocessor could access.